# What adapter do I need to mount a Konica lens on an Olympus E-520?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, lens-adapter, olympus, konica

I bought a Konica Super Albinar MC auto zoom 1:4.5 F=80-200 mm no. 911485 55 lens for my E-520 Olympus camera. The adapter I already have does not fit and I desperately need to know what kind of adapter to get.

Answer (score 2):

A Minolta MC/MD to 4/3 adapter would seem to fill the bill. There's one available [here](http://www.cameraquest.com/adapt_olyE1.htm) (at about $180), and there may be others (my search turned up a few discontinued makes). The MC lens is compatible with the Minolta MD mount, if that helps in your search at all.

Comment: Ebay offers such adapters too - price range 12-50 USD :-) http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_kw=Minolta&_kw=adapter&_kw=olympus

Comment: @Juhele: Might want to make that a full answer, with links to a couple examples. Even if a cheap one like that fails, you could get 3-15 of them for the price of one of the ones Stan linked. ;)

Comment: The key here, really, is in knowing that the lens mount is a Minolta type -- looking for a Konica adapter specifically is not likely to be fruitful. (And yes, cheaper is better if you're not giving up too much in the bargain. I came up craps on the first few low-priced adapters I found old links to, and wasn't terribly invested in finding a solution myself.)

Comment: @Stan: Agree, but some photo accessories are terribly expensive. You have to decide, how important each particular piece is for you. For example for me is nonsense to pay more than 30 USD for a original plastic lens hood (made in China, of course) while almost the same without the label "Pentax" costs less then 10USD: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=370216090932&ssPageName=ADME:L:OU:GB:1123 - I use it more than one year and I do not think I would appreciate the more expensive one by Pentax.